# TScriptControl - Class not registered

Tags: delphi, exception, vba

the following code sample works on 99% of PCs

```
CoInitialize(Nil);

  ScriptControl1:= TScriptControl.create(nil);
```

but one user bug report (madExcept) show this  :

```
exception class   : EOleSysError
exception message : Class not registered.

thread $414 (TCreate_restore_point):
004e90b5 +019 xxxx.exe ComObj                   OleError
004e90c8 +010 xxxx.exe ComObj                   OleCheck
0053e668 +04c xxxx.exe OleCtrls                 LicenseCheck
0053e75d +0e9 xxxx.exe OleCtrls                 TOleControl.CreateInstance
0053e125 +125 xxxx.exe OleCtrls                 TOleControl.Create
```

"ScriptControl1:= TScriptControl.create(nil);" raises an exception "Class not registered".

How can I register it or solve the issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need install the [`Windows Script Control`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1949) in the system in order to use the `TScriptControl` class.